# Update database table from one SQL Server database table to another?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to update database fields from one SQL Server table to another.

Our production SQL Server is `[spdbprod.test.com\spprod]`, our QA server is `[spdbQA.test.com\spQA]`.

I need to update table in production from QA table. I using this SQL statement but, it is giving an error.

```
UPDATE 
    [spdbprod.test.com\spprod].[aspnetdb].[dbo].[Communities_Groups] as t1
SET 
    t1.Show = (Select t2.show from [spdbQA.test.com\spQA].[aspnetdb].[dbo].
[Communities_Groups] as t2 where t1.GroupID = t2.GroupdID)
```

What I am missing here?
**Error:
UPDATE. ("Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.")**

Comment: If you post something like this and tease us with *it gives an error*, it would be best practice to **tell us** what the exact error is! That would be a tremendous help to see what the probelm might be....

Comment: @marc_s: I think one obvious error is table alias in `UPDATE`. ("Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.")

Comment: @a1ex07: that's a guess - a good one (upvoted you for that good guess), but still a guess.... and it's about general principle - don't just say "there is an error" - if you say that - TELL US what that error is!

Comment: @marc_s: Sure, I agree with you 100%

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are using table alias in a wrong way. You cannot do `UPDATE table1 t SET field1=val`, you have to write `UPDATE table1 SET field=val` (Or `UPDATE table1 SET field=val FROM table1 t`). So change your query to

```
UPDATE [spdbprod.test.com\spprod].[aspnetdb].[dbo].[Communities_Groups]   
SET Show = t2.show
FROM [spdbprod.test.com\spprod].[aspnetdb].[dbo].[Communities_Groups] t1
INNER JOIN [spdbQA.test.com\spQA].[aspnetdb].[dbo].
[Communities_Groups] t2 ON (t1.GroupID = t2.GroupID)
```

Comment: The form : "UPDATE t SET field=val FROM table1 t" also works.

Comment: Apparently, the `[dbo]` portion is more important than I would have thought. Nevertheless, you just saved my butt! Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I know this has been answered already but this worked for me.

- Add a Linked Server under Server Objects | Linked Servers:
  [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).
- Name the Linked Server `[SERVER-NAME or <some ipaddress>, <some-port>]`

  e.g. `[10.0.0.200,2345]` - *I am using port 2345 but the standard MS SQL port is 1433*.

**Example:**

- We have a `[Customers]` table
- We want to update `[CustomerAddress]`-field for `CustomerId = 123`
- We want to use backup data from a server called `[backupServer]`
- The `[backupServer]` is the machine where we execute the SQL

This is the SQL-code:

```
UPDATE production
SET
    CustomerAddress = backupServer.CustomerAddress
FROM 
    [10.0.0.200,2345].[ProductionDatabase].[dbo].[Customers] production
INNER JOIN 
    [BackupDatabase].[dbo].[Customers] backupServer
        ON 
            production.CustomerId = backupServer.CustomerId
WHERE 
    backupServer.CustomerId = 123
```

**Generalized format:**

```
UPDATE production
SET
    columnName = backupServer.columnName
FROM 
    [SERVER-NAME or IP,PORT].[ProductionDatabase].[dbo].[tableName] production
INNER JOIN 
    [BackupDatabase].[dbo].[tableName] backupServer
        ON 
            production.SomeId = backupServer.SomeId
WHERE 
    backupServer.SomeId = <id>
```

For those wanting to copy all data (INSERT) from a table from one server to another, it can be done with a command like this:

```
SELECT * INTO TargetTable 
FROM 
[SERVER-NAME or IP, PORT].[SourceDatabase].[dbo].[SourceTable]
```

This will create a new table called `TargetTable` using data from the `SourceTable` at the `SourceDatabase` at `SERVER-NAME or IP, PORT`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to have a database link (linked servers) for this to work.

I do not have access to two SQL servers here at work so I cannot test it, but I sure that you need the link.

Do you have a linked server setup?

Here is a URL that may help
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add a Linked Server under Server Objects
2. You can name that Linked Server either with "CHOOSEN-NAME" or
   [ipaddress , port number]

how to add a linked server using tsql , please check this link : [how to find linked server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54703816/1427614)

> for an example purpose suppose i have named the linked server
> "DESTINATION_SERVER" , database name is "DESTINATION_DB" and table
> name is "DESTINATION_TBL". then from your source server your query could be like this below:

```
UPDATE t1  
SET t1.updatecolumn = t2.updatecolumn
FROM [DESTINATION_SERVER].[DESTINATION_DB].[dbo].[DESTINATION_TBL] t1
INNER JOIN [SOURCE-SERVER].[SOURCE_DB].[dbo].
[SOURCE_TBL] t2 ON (t1.matcingcolumn = t2.matchingcolumn)
```